# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,2) into shape (20)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
import os

import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from keras.applications import Xception, VGG16, ResNet50

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

base_dir = 'NewDCDatatset'


train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Train')

validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Validation')

test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Test')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

batch_size = 20

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7 , 7 , 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='categorical')
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 9900*2)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, 1300*2)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 2600)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (9900*2, 7 * 7 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (2600, 7 * 7 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (2600, 7 * 7 * 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=7 * 7 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels,epochs=3,batch_size=50,shuffle=True)
print(model.evaluate(test_features,test_labels))

model.save('TLFACE.h5')
```

Hi here is my code and i am getting above error. I am unable to understand where to change its shape from (20) to (20,2), actually I was working on binary classification but now want to work on multi classification and unable to fix this. any help will be appreciated, thanks. Below full details of error is given.

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" C:/Users/SIBAU/Downloads/face-recognition-with-deep-learning-python-master/extract_text.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-05-28 14:46:37.336572: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-05-28 14:46:37.376451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-05-28 14:47:08.730218: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-05-28 14:47:08.730502: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-05-28 14:47:08.909845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: BILAL-LAPTOP
2020-05-28 14:47:08.910341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: BILAL-LAPTOP
2020-05-28 14:47:08.932583: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Found 80 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SIBAU/Downloads/face-recognition-with-deep-learning-python-master/extract_text.py", line 31, in <module>
    train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 9900*2)
  File "C:/Users/SIBAU/Downloads/face-recognition-with-deep-learning-python-master/extract_text.py", line 25, in extract_features
    labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,2) into shape (20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing multiclass classification (one answer per input , where the answer may be one-of-n possibilities) then I blv. the problem may be remedied using

```
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='sparse')
```

From the [docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/), "categorical" is for 2D one-hot encoded labels,  "binary" will be 1D binary labels, "sparse" will be 1D integer labels.  Since you don't want multi-label but rather multiclass, use sparse.  The 1 dimension of sparse is the batch dimension, while the 2 dimensions of one-hot is 1 dimension for batch and another for a set of labels .

If you are actually doing multiclass classification (more than one output class per input , like labelling both animal type and fruit type in an image) then you would prob. want

```
labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count),2)
```

which allows for 2 labels (in this case) per input.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy_rutman for this help, it worked for me. Just to correct you bit, working command is => labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,2)) not => labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count),2)